# Image not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, image

Something really weird is happening on my website, there is an image that is not displaying!

The problem seems to be file extension. Theoretically, the file extension is *.png* (but it seems it is *.PNG* somehow)

**Here is a screenshot**

[image]

**How this happened??** and **How can I change the image extension back to *.png*??**

I really don't want to put *.PNG* on the CSS file!

Comment: rename the file to use a lowercase png then? Or set your server to be case insensitive.

Comment: Say the magic words... since you obviously live in realm of magic where SO users can see into your mind.

Comment: @Ivan Ivanić. what magic words? please?

Comment: No, magic words like what is your environment. http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: You need to provide some context. How is anyone supposed to know why that file has PNG in caps? Was it uploaded by ftp, http, from your computer, by a user, was it already there? If you want to know how to rename it then how do you have access to your server? Through ftp, webadmin, root access, console, etc, etc, etc. This question cannot be answered.

Comment: `% mv pager_bg.PNG pager_bg.png` | `C:\somewhere> ren pager_bg.PNG pager_bg.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1:

FTP to server

Step 2:

right click on file and rename to pager_bg.png

Step 3:

refresh browser

Assuming your CSS has the correct value all will work as you expect now.

Comment: For general question, general answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the first answer, however, if that does not work. Try removing it completely from the website and the FTP server, wait about 5 minutes or when you see results that it is not there. Then add it back in.

Comment: This is a magic incantation, not an answer. Why would that make a difference? And why 5 minutes?

Comment: Perhaps there's a spell to go with it.

Comment: No because in every webserver that most people would know if they program using like a unix or Linux base server that there is a default refresh rate on a server before changes actually take place. The default is from 5 to 15 minutes. Now you may see results almost instant, but with big coding or with large files, it takes time to process. If you don't know what I am talking about, I suggest you google it to find out more. Most of the time I have to contact support to get them to change the default to 0 so changes are instant.